# Dynamically adding event listeners by name

Tags: event-handling, dart

How would you translate this function from Javascript into Dart?

```javascript
function addEvtListener(Element el, evtName, fn) {
    return el.addEventListener ? el.addEventListener(evtName, fn, false) : el.attachEvent('on' + evtName, fn);
}
```

The main issue is having the event name dynamic.  I obviously can call:

```dart
el.onClick.listen((event) => fn(event));
```

if the `evtName` is a click event.  But is there a method like this in Dart?

```dart
el.on("click").listen(event) => fn(event));
```

Answer (score 3):

The Events class documentation has an overview of the different ways to listen for an event by name: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Events.html

You'll see that you can do both:

```dart
new EventStreamProvider(evtName).forTaget(el).listen(fn);
```

or

```
el.on[evtName].listen(fn);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```dart
(const EventStreamProvider<Event>(evtName)).forTarget(el).listen((e) => fn(e));
```